# List view displaying items in random order

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In my application i am parsing my data from URL and after parsing I want to view them in a List view up to this point i am successful but the links which I get from URL are not ordered, The list view displays my links in random. I am using a custom adapter in which i have get view() method. I am new to android thanks

below is my get view() method

[image: getview]

Answer (score 0):

you see the "position" param in getView() method. that's for your display oder. u may confirm the display position before inflate your content.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am not getting you please can you explain it further thanking you

Comment: hi dude, plz upload a screencut to show how it's "not ordered". Cuz listview shows it's children in order.

Comment: I created a small ListView with text {A, B, C, D} and the order of the items seemed to be random. I haven't found a solution yet. This is pretty terrible though, since you may scan items and show them in the List. If you have a parallel array of objects, they won't line up. I would also like additional information about the positioning.